# the purpose of creating an h2o model

Tags: tensorflow, sparkling-water

In the demo code
    https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/py/examples/notebooks/TensorFlowDeepLearning.ipynb

I can more or less make out what the code is doing. My question is what is the advantage in creating the h2o model at the end for running it repeatedly. How is that better than just deploy the model in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically training over 1 more pass of the data, which means the model has double the amount of steps to learn.  Remember that any gradient descent sort of deep learning are progressing towards a local minimum in steps, so if you run 1 pass of the full data, it might not have arrive at the optimal point yet, so you might get better loss after more training.

Comment: Don't think I got my point across. Why don't you just keep running tensorflow if you want more training passes? The question is why create an h2o model at all, instead of staying within the bound of tensorflow.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "keep running tensorflow"?

Comment: When you are doing training on tensorflow, you are already running the training in iterations. So I am saying, in order to get closer to the global / local minimum, as you are describing, just increase the number of iterations on tensorflow. Why create a h2o model to do more iterations.

Comment: That's exactly what the page is trying to say.  It trains for one epoch (making a full pass through the data), results is not good enough, so it runs 1 more epoch (another full pass through the training data)  to try to get to better results.

Comment: I don't know why we are not connecting. You see the caption "Convert the TensorFlow model into a H2O Deep Learning model", where they made the call dlmodel = H2ODeepLearningEstimator(... then it did "Extract the Java scoring code (POJO) for the TensorFlow model". followed by a whole bunch java code in model_from_TF.java. Is all that just a wrapper for tensorflow code? if so, what exactly is the value added for the wrapper.